# Auto next step when clicked in radio on multi step form Elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, elementor

I have a multi step form in Elementor with radio input, and I want to move to the next step when clicked in radio, now I need to click NEXT to move to next page, 2 clicks to move ahead, but I want just one..

Is that possibe to move automaticly afer clicked in radio option to the next step?

I doens't understant java scritp to do this if someone can help me I'll appreceate

Answer (score 0):

write onclick on radio input same as Next button

Comment: There is no way to do that in elementor form! It's not pure html or javascript, the dashboard of the widget form doens't have this option.

Comment: Hi @JorgeBusanaJunior Did you find any workaround for this ? I have exactly same scenario and was wondering how to do it.